# Spring Security oauth2Login and httpBasic using multiple WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

Tags: spring-security, okta, spring-boot-actuator

I need to expose API's protected by Okta login(oauth2Login), and in addition to expose actuator endpoints.
actuator endpoints need to be protected with basic authentication(httpBasic).
I have created two WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter based on the corresponding requestMatchers, where the ActuatorSecurityConfiguration having the HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE order.
The problem is that when i am hitting actuator endpoint, it is entering oauth2 authentication flow instead of httpBasic, i am  expecting to get the basic authentication popup, but instead it redirecting to oauth login screen. it looks like okta-spring-boot-starter autoconfiguration is ignoring any other configuration and force oauth2Login for all the defined WebSecurityConfigurerAdapters, regardless to the order and requestMatchers?

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class ActuatorSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.requestMatchers().antMatchers("/monitoring/**").and()
                .httpBasic()
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/monitoring/health").permitAll()
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().hasRole("ACTUATOR")
                .and().csrf().disable()
                ;
    }
```

and OktaSecurityConfiguration :

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
@Order(Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class OktaSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        http
                .requestMatchers().antMatchers("/rest/**").and()
                .oauth2Login()
...
```

mvn dependency tree :

```
+- com.okta.spring:okta-spring-boot-starter:jar:2.1.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.okta.spring:okta-spring-security-oauth2:jar:2.1.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:2.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.okta.commons:okta-config-check:jar:1.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.okta.commons:okta-commons-lang:jar:1.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-jose:jar:5.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-resource-server:jar:5.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.okta.spring:okta-spring-sdk:jar:2.1.5:compile
...
+- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:jar:2.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:5.3.15:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:5.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:5.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:5.6.1:compile
...
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:jar:2.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure:jar:2.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator:jar:2.6.1:compile
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was wrong error handling for case where there is a missing authentication basic header in the "/monitoring/**" request, it was falling to LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint and accordingly redirecting to oauth login screen.
Resolved by adding authenticationEntryPoint for ActuatorSecurityConfiguration in order to respond with "WWW-Authenticate" header and popup on the browser.

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class ActuatorSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.requestMatchers().antMatchers("/monitoring/**").and()
                .httpBasic()
                .and().exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(actuatorBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint())
                .and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/monitoring/health").permitAll()
                .and().authorizeRequests().anyRequest().hasRole("ACTUATOR")
                .and().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and().csrf().disable()
                ;
    }

    @Bean
    AuthenticationEntryPoint actuatorBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint() {
        return new AuthenticationEntryPoint() {
            @Override
            public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException, ServletException {
                response.addHeader("WWW-Authenticate", "Basic realm=\"" + "realmName" + "\"");
                response.sendError(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value(), HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.getReasonPhrase());
            }
        };
    }
```